# animateScrollToPage with slow sliding animation in Accompanist Pager

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Is there a way to slow down the sliding interval when auto-scrolling to next page in Accompanist Pager?

In the latest version, support for the same has been removed.

```
The animationSpec, initialVelocity and skipPages parameters on animateScrollToPage() have been removed. The lazy components handle this automatically.
```

Currently, the auto scroll to next page moves very quickly.

```
pager.animateScrollToPage(pageIndex)
```

Accompanist Pager version used: 0.22.1-rc

Comment: Consider participating to this issue on github: https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1261

Answer (score 2):

An answer can be found [here](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1261).

This animates `Card` components that auto-scroll forward then back to the start, in a loop.

**States**

```kotlin
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
val isDragged by pagerState.interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()
var pageSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
val lastIndex by remember(pagerState.currentPage) {
        derivedStateOf {pagerState.currentPage == items.size - 1 }
    }
```

**Scroll**

```kotlin
if (!isDragged) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            yield()
            delay(2000)
            pagerState.animateScrollBy(
                value = if (lastIndex) - (pageSize.width.toFloat() * items.size) else pageSize.width.toFloat(),
                animationSpec = tween(if (lastIndex) 2000 else 1400)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**pageSize** is assigned with an `onSizeChanged` `Modifier` on the `Card`

```kotlin
HorizontalPager(
        count = items.size,
        state = pagerState
    ) { pageIndex ->
        Card(modifier = modifier.onSizeChanged { pageSize = it } ) { /* card content */ }
    }
```

Comment: when adding `contentPadding` and `pageSpacing` to the horizontal pager the scolling is messed up. any idea how to calculate the page size with those padding?

Comment: @TheDragoner I replied to [the equivalent comment on github](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1261#issuecomment-2016864594) since stackoverflow comments have such a small character limit.